# How to install tensorflow in windows 10 operating system after installed everything still got an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

import tensorflow

It shows

2020-06-16 07:15:04.362632: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-06-16 07:15:04.394714: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

install everything what tensorflow needs 
and download everything still won't get the program

Answer (score 0):

Most people are missing the vs2019 redist lib. Make sure you install that

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: I already did that still error is exist in the error

Comment: oh i did not read the whole error ..  install the cuda drivers and make sure you add to the path the folder that contains that DLL.. DO NOT INSTALL THE LATEST .. you need version 10.1   here is the link https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update2?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but in case where it is usefull for someone:
the problem here is that Cuda 10.1 should be installed. You also need CuDNN 7.6 to run tensorflow with GPU. All information are available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu. By the way it is better to use the most recent versions of tensorflow (for now it is the combo CUDA 11.2 and CuDNN 8.1)